# JAWS doesn't read div after pressing skip to link in Internet Explorer

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, accessibility, tabindex

On our website, http://www.discovertechnologies.com, we have a Skip to Content link that upon pressing enter on it sends the JAWS user to the main content and immediately begins to read whatever is in the div marked by id=“main”; like it should. However, for some reason this only works successfully in Chrome and Firefox but not in Internet Explorer.

In IE11 the screen shifts down to "read" the main content, but JAWS will not read what is in the div.  I’ve researched the web to find a solution but haven’t been able to, which is why I reach out to you. For what it's worth our website is WordPress based. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in [this article on skip links](http://webaim.org/techniques/skipnav/#quirks), in-page links can have different behavior across browsers. What's happening in IE is that IE is only scrolling the page - it's not actually moving focus (you can verify this by checking document.activeElement in the console) - and since there's no focus change, JAWS remains silent.

A simple workaround is to use javascript to set focus:

```
<a onclick="jQuery('#main').focus()" href="javascript:void(0)">Skip to content</a>
```

The `href="javascript:void(0)"` here is to suppress navigation - otherwise IE will essentially re-navigate to the page, potentially interfering with focus.

Comment: You'll also want to make sure that element is programmatically focusable by adding `tabindex="-1"` to the element if it is not of a type that is not natively focusable (like a div).

Comment: The OP's original code already has the `tabindex="-1"` - but worth calling out here in case other folks read this qu in future!

Comment: Hi, OP here. So, as this is a WordPress site and the skip to content link was created by a plugin, I edited the plugin by converting your line of code into: 

$html .= ( $content != '' ) ? "<a onclick=\"jQuery('#$content').focus()\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\">" . __( 'Skip to content', 'wp-accessibility' ) . "</a> " : '';

This didn't allow the skip to content link to work anymore. I contacted the plugin developer and after some testing told me that the some script in my theme is overriding the behavior set up by the plug-in so that it does not properly move focus. Any sugg. on how to fix it?

Comment: I also tried including this without the plugin. The code you provided doesn't even cause the screen to shift down. Your solution doesn't work either way. Thanks for trying!

Comment: Works fine for me - try http://jsbin.com/nedokeyoqe/1 - JAWS+IE scrolls and announces as expected. View/Source and scroll to bottom to see how I added the code above into the site. This solution does work; so I'm wondering if you're hitting other unrelated HTML or wordpress issues.